# Center Image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I adopted some code to make my logo have a transparent background on top of a parallax image. Once I did this, for some reason, I could get the logo back to the center of the screen. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
      ...
</nav>

<div id="homepage-front-logo">
    <img src="images/logo-placeholder.png" class="img-fluid" />
</div>
<div class="parallax-header-image"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.homepage-front-logo {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#homepage-front-logo {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I added a red border so that I could see the actual div and I saw that the `width` was the culprit. It was centering but I was telling the surrounding div to be only 300px wide. I changed it to 100% and used @abney317's idea of the `text-align` then presto.

```
.homepage-front-logo {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with only Bootstrap native classes, no css modifications.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
      ...
</nav>

<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center" id="homepage-front-logo">
   <img src="https://i.ibb.co/129nyzN/qqqlogo.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto" />
</div>
<div class="parallax-header-image"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working for me. It's still flushing to the left. Only the body tag is encapsulating it and I applied no styling to it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if I understand correctly, but you should be able to get the image centered by changing you #homepage-front-logo CSS

```
#homepage-front-logo {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```